# not all code paths return a value in class

Tags: c#, class

i know this a question who has been asked before , but i could not resolve this

i want to write a class to detect and return color but i get this error  : not all code paths return a value in class

```
class Class1
{


    public System.Drawing.Color colordetector(string name)
    {

        if (name.Contains("blue") == true) { return System.Drawing.Color.Blue; }
        if (name.Contains("green") == true) { return System.Drawing.Color.Green; }
        if (name.Contains("red") == true) { return System.Drawing.Color.Red; }



    }//method colordetector



}//class1
```

Comment: What if `name`'s value isn't blue, green or red?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev : thanks its solved i should write a "else statement "

Comment: you also don't need == true in your if statement, contains () already returns true/false

Comment: The other questions you no doubt looked at would apply in your case.  Just because you are returning a `Color` does not alter the concept and make your situation unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets look at your class...

[image]

So you've crated a method .. and have defined (in the method signature) that the class returns a `System.Drawing.Color`.

Now, looking at the code *inside* this method ... you're doing *three* `if` checks.

BUT what happens if `name` is `'black' ? what will happen then? it will not pass each of those three if-checks and then do what?

the code needs to handle the scenario when there colour is *not* found.

Solutions:

- Throw an exception if the colour passed in was not found/handled.
- Return a default colour if the colour passed in was not found/handled.

Answer (score 1):

If all `if` conditions fails, your method doesn't return any result..

The failure condition :

String doesn't contain `blue` , `green` or `red`

```
public System.Drawing.Color colordetector(string name)
{

    if (name.Contains("blue")) { return System.Drawing.Color.Blue; }

    if (name.Contains("green")) { return System.Drawing.Color.Green; }
    if (name.Contains("red")) { return System.Drawing.Color.Red; }

       // < == ????? What if all failled ?? what to retun 
}//method colordetector
```

A solution would be to return a `color` of your choice that would state an error has occurred.

```
public System.Drawing.Color colordetector(string name)
{

    if (name.Contains("blue")) { return System.Drawing.Color.Blue; }

    if (name.Contains("green")) { return System.Drawing.Color.Green;    }
    if (name.Contains("red")) { return System.Drawing.Color.Red; }

     return System.Drawing.Color.Black; // <= Default to send Black if all conditions failled

}//method colordetector
```

Comment: Or maybe that _default_ should be `Color.Transparent`? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You method doens't return any value, **if** the variable called `name` doesn't contain one of the words blue, green and red.

The return type of your method is `System.Drawing.Color`. Hence you should always return a `System.Drawing.Color` value.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have specified a return type and the return statement only appears to be placed inside the if blocks.

So in case if none of your if condition evaluates to true the method will never return anything hence it gives you this message.

A workaround is returning some default color and have a logic to check default color where you are calling this method.

Edit: It will not allow you to return null because it is a non-nullable value type